# VueJS axios allow to click button only once, second time allow after data received

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

I am doing like/dislike system on Laravel/VueJS.

[image]

My system works, but I want to avoid spammers.

Like button:

```
<a v-on:click="like(10, $event)">
    <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
</a>
```

10 is post id, it is generated in laravel blade...

This is what I tried to do to avoid spammers:

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data() {
    return {
        allowed: true,
    };
},
methods: {
    like: function (id, event) {
        if (this.allowed) {
            axios.post('/posts/' + id + '/like', {  
                post_id: id,
            })
            .then((response) => {
                this.allowed = false; //Set allowed to false, to avoid spammers.

                ..... code which changes fa-heart, changes class names, texts etc ....

                // send notification to user
                Vue.toasted.show('Bla bla bla successfuly liked post', {
                    duration: 2000,
                    onComplete: (function () {
                        this.allowed = true //After notification ended, user gets permission to like/dislike again.
                    })
                });
```

But something is missing here, or I am doing something wrong. When I click very very fast on like icon, and check requests, axios sends 3-4-5 requests (depends how fast u click)

[image]

And only after that 3-5 requests `data.allowed` becomes `false`. Why? I want to:

1. allowed = true;
2. User clicks like -> allowed = false; > clicks second time "You are not allowed to click again, because previous notification not ended";
3. Previous notification ended -> allowed = true;
4. ... loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    like: function (id, event) {
        // first, check if the `like` can be sent to server
        if (!this.allowed) return;
        // remember that we are sending request, not allowed to `like` again
        this.allowed = false;

        var self = this;  // you need this to remember real this
        axios.post('/posts/' + id + '/like', {  
            post_id: id,
        }).then((response) => {
            ..... code ....

            // send notification to user
            Vue.toasted.show('Bla bla bla successfuly liked post', {
                duration: 2000,
                onComplete: function () {
                    //After notification ended, user gets permission to like/dislike again.
                    self.allowed = true;
                }
            );
       }).catch(function() {
            // maybe you also need this catch, in case network error occurs
            self.allowed = true;
       })
        ....
```

Answer (score 1):

The `this.allowed = false;` is beeing called until the API call finish so you can spam more within that time.
Set it to `false` immediately after the comprobation `if (this.allowed)`.

```
if (this.allowed) {
    this.allowed = false; // Then do the call
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for me works, @click.once

```
<q-btn
@click.once ="selectItemFiles(options)"
/>
```

No matter how many times the user clicks, the action will be produced only one time